# How do I utilize an ActiveRecord validator outside of model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an ActiveRecord validator of

```
validates :content, length: { in: 1..400 }
```

In my view I would like to show the maximum allowed character length (400) by referring to the validator (so that I am not setting the value of 400 in more than one spot).  I'm using Rails 4.  Any suggestions on what would a good approach?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.validators_on(:content).find{|v| v.class == ActiveRecord::Validations::LengthValidator}.options[:maximum]
```

Comment: In Rails 4 Validations was moved to ActiveRecord so I think it would be `Model.validators_on(:content).find{|v| v.class == ActiveRecord::Validations::LengthValidator}.options` and to get just the max `Model.validators_on(:content).find{|v| v.class == ActiveRecord::Validations::LengthValidator}.options[:maximum]`

Comment: @engineersmnky: Modified my answer. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Because we're hacking around in Ruby, I also like: `Model.validators_on(:content).find{|v| v.class.name[/LengthValidator/] }.options`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I ended up adding [:maximum] to the end of Vimsha's statement.  I know this is outside the scope of the question, but how could I grab this value in a CoffeeScript?  If you insist I can ask another question.